# ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED while using BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher in C++/WinRT

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm trying to use BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher to detect BLE advertising packets. However upon calling Start() the watcher object always aborts with 'Access is denied' error.

Code is pretty simple and is as below:

```
auto filter = BluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter();
auto advert = BluetoothLEAdvertisement();
advert.LocalName(L"Greeny");
filter.Advertisement(advert);
m_watcher.AdvertisementFilter(filter);

// setup event handlers
m_watcher.Received({ this, &MainPage::OnAdvertisementRecieved });
m_watcher.Stopped({ this, &MainPage::OnAdvertisementStopped });

m_watcher.Start();
```

m_watcher is a class member declared as:

```
BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher m_watcher;
```

The event handlers are declared as:

```
void MainPage::OnAdvertisementRecieved(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher const& watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs const& args)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"Bluetooth advertisement received!\n");
}

void MainPage::OnAdvertisementStopped(Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher const & watcher, Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement::BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs const & args)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"Advertising stopped\n");
}
```

This code is pretty similar to the sample code in the SDK which is in C#. I'm trying to do the same in C++ as I'm more familiar with it.

Any idea what could be going wrong? I tried removing all the filters, that is, using the watcher in its default state. That too gives the same error. Removing the event handlers also results in the same error.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Changed the title adding ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

EDIT2: The exact location where the error occurs is:
onecoreuap\drivers\wdm\bluetooth\user\winrt\advertisement\bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher.cpp(1510)\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll!0F479314: (caller: 0F47AD40) Exception(2) tid(2c1c) 80070005 Access is denied.

Comment: m_watcher.ScanningMode = Active; before calling Start()

Comment: Just tried that. Doesn't help. I would think that the Watcher object in its default state should be able to start listening for advert packets and reporting them through the callback. At least this seems to be the behavior in the C# code. And C++/WinRT ought to be using the same underlying WRL object whether it's instantiated from C++/WinRT or C#.

Comment: It depends on how WinRT was initialized. If you application initializes COM somhow before WinRT initialization you may get strange behaviour..

Comment: I suspected this. The original WinRT app used to initialize COM in a single-threaded apartment (done internally). I wrote another program that explicitly initializes COM as a multi-threaded apartment and tried the above code. There too I get the same error. Searching more online, I see that this used to be an issue in earlier Windows releases which apparently has been fixed in release 17xx and I'm at 1803. Unless there's a regression wrt this. Currently I'm trying to explicitly initialize COM security using CoInitializeSecurity() and see if that solves the problem. So far no success.

Comment: We found at least 3 Bluetooth bugs in 1803. But the feature you are trying to use works OK. Try to initialize WinRT manually from separate thread. I mean: start separate thread and in this thread call WinRT initialization as multithreaded. Then call other WInRT from this seperate thread.

Comment: Try to run this: http://www.btframework.com/beacon.zip Click "Open" and then "StartMonitoring".

Comment: Thanks. I tried, and I get the error 'Bluetooth Manager was not opened'. I'm using Windows 10 Home v1803. I presume this is based on your proprietary code. Have you tested it on Windows 10?

Comment: Click "Open" first. Then "Start Monitoring". It uses WinRT as I described above: in separate thread. Yes of course it is tested on Win 10 (starting from 16XX).

Comment: I see. Yes, it does detect the advert packets. Bizarre, why I can't get it to work. I must be missing something.

Comment: Your code looks absolutely correct. The only one thing is different: Our code starts thread, in this thread we call RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED); Then create Watcher instance then set scanning mode, assign handler and start Wantcher. That's all we do there. Thread keeps running (waiting on Event). When our code needs to stop Watcher it sets the Event, its signals and the Thread exits (before exiting it stops Watcher, release handler and uninit WinRT).

Comment: Oh, by the way, if you develop UWP app you must specify device capabilities (I completly forget about that cause we usualy work with classic Win32 apps). You can find more there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-for-bluetooth

Comment: Thanks!! I'll have a look. Mine's indeed a UWP app. I was toying around with the new C++/WinRT framework too see how far one can go in terms of using for a production app. I have long been a Windows developer, but been away from the scene for a good 4~5 years and therefore missed the caravan that took most hardcore Windows developers to UWP.

Comment: Yes, lack of device capabilities in the manifest was the issue. It works now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MikePetrichenko please could you post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it.  That way future readers will find an answered question.

Answer (score 3):

Solution Explorer -> Package.appxmanifest -> Capabilities -> Bluetooth (check)

Comment: I don't know why did they down vote this comment. It fixed my problem. Thank you Joe. 
Up.

Answer (score 1):

It is good idea to set m_watcher.ScanningMode = Active; before calling Start();

Also, if you develop non UWP (classic) application you should be sure that WinRT initialized correctly. As WinRT based on COM technologyy it is good to initialize WinRT before any other call to COM is made. However some applications based on any frameworks (for example, MFC, Delphi VCL or others) may initialize COM internally with custom parameters. In this case it is good idea to call RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED) from separate thread.

Microsoft write that WinRT must be initialized with RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED flag. However our experience shows that usingother flags also works but all the WinRT events will be executed synchronous then. Not good for work.

And finally if you develop UWP application **do not forget** to set application device capabilities as described there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-for-bluetooth

This is important thing.