# How to add Bluetooth to capabilities in Flutter Windows App

Tags: c++, windows, flutter, bluetooth

I am creating flutter windows plugin with c++ which uses bluetooth device. The problem is my app is crashing just before I start scanning because of similar reason as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50756531/11984583).

In the answers, they suggested adding `bluetooth` in `Capabilities` in appxmanifest in windows. But how can I do this for flutter project? I tried `msix` package for this, but to no avail. I would really appreciate your help if you could help me on this!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: Are you developing flutter plugin using c++ native windows? I solved the issue but I can't remember exactly how I did it. The problem was related to scanning

Comment: The winRT api lets you do alot of stuff, but issues remain when working with devices already paired with windows. Not sure how to pair without pairing :/