# Setting a WinRt AdvertisementFilter() to a substring of LocalName

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt

C++, WinRT, VS2017, Win10

I create a watcher to look for my Bluetooth LE device with

```
BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher;
```

Now I want to set a filter for for the device that I am specifically looking for.  Let's say that the LocalName for the device is "MyDevice_ABC1234".  I can do this with

```
watcher.AdvertisementFilter().Advertisement().LocalName().c_str() == L"MyDevice_ABC1234";
```

But what I really want to do is set the filter to the manufacture's name and not the specific model number.  I want to filter for "MyDevice" being in the LocalName.  This would be easy enough given the luxury of a few lines of code but how would it be done in the context of

```
watcher.AdvertisementFilter().Advertisement().LocalName()
```

LocalName() has an operator for basic_string_view which has a find() method but for the life of me I can't get that to work properly.  The find() is supposed to return the npos so I tried:

```
watcher.AdvertisementFilter().Advertisement().LocalName().operator std::basic_string_view<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>>.find("MyDevice") == 8;
```

I actually tried this as simple code so I could debug the results with

```
hstring hstrLocalName = L"MyDevice_aBC1234";
bool bFind = hstrLocalName.operator std::basic_string_view<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>>.find("MyDevice", 0) == 8;
```

and also

```
int iFind = hstrLocalName.operator std::basic_string_view<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>>.find("MyDevice", 0);
```

But neither of these worked. They compiled but just never executed. Is there a way to get the basic_string_view.find() to work or would there be a better way to do this?

Comment: C++/WinRT uses the following convention for accessing properties: `T foo()` returns property `foo`, and `void foo(T)` sets property `foo`. All of the calls above only read out the properties. They never actually set them (not that I'd know how the filters are actually meant to work). Also, those explicit `.operator string_view` invocations aren't actually required. Since you get *one* user-defined implicit conversion for free, `hstrLocalName.find(...)` should just work. If it doesn't, try moving to a more recent compiler. VS2017 is actually a bit old for C++/WinRT.

Comment: There is no property "filter" but there is a property "LocalName".  In the first example it is just comparing the property LocalName to "MyDevice_ABC1234" and, it the comparison is true, then it will filter for that.  At least that is my understanding.  However, I'm pretty sure that LocalName equal to "MyDevice" will never be true.  Also LocalName greater than or less than "MyDevice" may or may not be true depending or what else is out there.  So I was trying to figure out a way to create a single boolean statement that would translate to true if "MyDevice" was part of the full LocalName.

Comment: You aren't ever **setting** a filter. All you're doing is reading properties. I'm pretty sure that some of those statements will raise compiler warnings about unused return values or expression results. Again, I haven't done any advertisement filtering, though I'm pretty sure you'll have to **set** the `Advertisement` property (or at least set at least one of its properties). Yet, the code shown, only ever **reads** properties. You'll probably need to take a step back and first understand how WinRT properties are projected into C++/WinRT.

Comment: But the docs say     >Gets or sets a BluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter object used for configuration of Bluetooth LE advertisement filtering that uses payload section-based filtering.  So wouldn't the == be setting the filter?

Comment: No, that merely invokes the binary `operator==`. Neither operand is changed. You're still in the *"gets"* part of the properties. See my first comment to see how to **set** a property.

Comment: I realize that now but the foo(T) does not seem to work.  No matter how I try and format the command I get Intellisense errors.  In all of Google (here in StackOverflow -- search for "filter.Advertisement(advert)" ) there is only one example of a filter being applied and that method causes my watcher to return nothing even though I have 2 BLE devices advertising.  I have to get on to other BLE problems so I will probably drop this for now and return to it later...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see now, that when I do use the method mentioned above from StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756531/error-access-denied-while-using-bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher-in-c-winrt), it does filter for the LocalName that I set. However, and I remember this warning from the docs somewhere, that some advertisement packets come with the local name but not Uuids and visa versa.  As it happenes, that is why I thought the filter was catching nothing.  I was ignoring any packets that did not have services and these were the ones with the LocalName.  Catch22.

For what it is worth,  here is the method for setting a filter mentioned in the link above that also worked for me (with caveats)

```
auto filter = BluetoothLEAdvertisementFilter();
auto advert = BluetoothLEAdvertisement();
advert.LocalName(L"MyDevice_ABC1234");
filter.Advertisement(advert);
watcher.AdvertisementFilter(filter);
```